# unserscore,use "{{","}}" as interpolated symbol,i got an exception

Tags: javascript, templates, underscore.js

how could i made it work?
underscore 1.8
the exception :
SyntaxError: expected expression, got ')'
any help will be apprecicate!

```
{{_.each(data,function(item){}}
<tr>
    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{item.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{item.age}}</td>
</tr>
 {{});}}
```

overcome some trouble,the code worked

```
_.templateSettings = {
      interpolate: /\{\{=(.+?)\}\}/g,
      evaluate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g,
    };
```

the template

```
{{_.each(data,function(item){}}
<tr>
    <td>{{=item.name}}</td>
    <td>{{=item.gender}}</td>
    <td>{{=item.age}}</td>
</tr>
{{})}}
```

refrenced [each loop in underscore.js template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361185/each-loop-in-underscore-js-template)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [guidelines](http://underscorejs.org/#template) template setting should be updated for this.  Would be great if you could share code with code pen example as code you posted not making a lot of sense.

```
_.templateSettings = {
  interpolate: /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
};

var template = _.template("Hello {{ name }}!");
template({name: "Mustache"});
=> "Hello Mustache!"
```

Comment: thanks for your help,i have already got the templateSettings,
 got it work ,and ,in my condition ,also ,need the evalute setting!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361185/each-loop-in-underscore-js-template